# Error on method call to validate the textbox

Tags: vb.net

I want to call method to validate the textbox, but the following crash occurs:

```
Private e As Object

Public Sub ValidX_keyPress()
    If Not Char.IsNumber(e.keychar) And Not Char.IsControl(e.keychar) Then
        MsgBox("please")
        e.handled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub tbxOne_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles tbxOne.KeyPress
    ValidX_keyPress()
End Sub
```

> Crash: Additional information: Object variable or With block variable not set.

Answer (score 1):

You are using e in the ValidX_keyPress Method, but there is no e. Look at the solution:

```
    Private e As Object
    Public Sub ValidX_keyPress(e As KeyPressEventArgs)
        If Not Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) And Not Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then
            MsgBox("please")
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub tbxOne_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles tbxOne.KeyPress
        ValidX_keyPress(e)
    End Sub
```

You need to define e as parameter in ValidX_keyPress and then provide e when calling the method.

Comment: Why did you remove the answer flag? Whats the problem?